# The import android.nfc.INfcSecureElement cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-emulator

I got some sample code for android.nfc.NfcSecureElement but it throws some error.

```
The import android.nfc.INfcSecureElement cannot be resolved
```

Any suggestion how I can overcome this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NFC API was added in API level 9, so ensure that your project utilizes the level 9 platform in your Project => Android => Project Build Target.

Comment: My project build target is Android 2.3.3 and API level 10.

Comment: Fair enough. Not sure where your sample code came from, but it appears that that interface isn't publicly available.

Comment: But at least I can import it rite. I got the error when I try to import it.

Comment: Nope. There's nothing to import, it isn't anywhere that Eclipse (or the build system) can find it.

Comment: How do I add in my eclipse? For your info  import android.nfc.tech.TagTechnology is working without error.